# JS Navigation in gallery based on where user clicks

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using the **Royalslider WP** plugin and a very minimal simple fade gallery, and there is the option to `navigate-by-click` which means the user can click anywhere and the next image loads.

What I would like to achieve is to have a 50%-50% line and if the user clicks on the left side of the screen, the previous image loads, and if clicks on the right side, the next image loads.

I found this but I can't get my head around writing the rest of the necessary JS code.

http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/problems/58856-navigatebyclick-previousnext-slide-based-on-cursor-position

http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/wordpress-royalslider-advanced/wp-where-to-put-slider-javascript-api-code

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!